# Uploading 2 individual files via Flask for Python Processing

Tags: python, pandas, flask

started playing with Flask and am looking to convert a few easy python scripts to be able to run through a web interface. Mostly data tweaking tools.

So, most of the tools that I have running through the command line use 2 spreadsheets and then perform operations between them using pandas (look for differences, update information, etc).

However, I can't seem to figure out how to create the interface needed to allow for users viewing the site to have 2 upload buttons (1 for each file) and then underneath that have a process button where the magic happens.

All of the documentation I have encountered either deals with uploading a single file (and then run whatever process) or allow for multiple file uploads with a single upload button.

So, a basic template would be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h2>Upload Current File Here</h2>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type=file name=curfile>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Upload New File Here</h2>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type=file name=newfile>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for the app.py, this is the version that will load a single file and process.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pandas as pd
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["ALLOWED_FILE_EXTENSIONS"] = ["xlsx"]
app.config["MAX_IMAGE_FILESIZE"] = 16 * 1024 * 1024


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dfcur = pd.read_excel(request.files.get('curfile'))
        
    return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Hope what I posted makes sense, been looking through a lot of notes online and haven't found anything that addresses the workflow yet. I know the issue is that the file is uploaded and then the template is rendered, whereas I want to allow for both to be uploaded before doing anything.

Comment: For more clarification, the following site [Link](https://products.groupdocs.app/comparison/xlsx) has a similar interface as far as 2 individual file uploads go, although it looks like it is using javascript to get the job done:

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research and going over the code I managed to make it work by adding an additional request.files for the additional file name.

I still have to incorporate what to do with the files, as this code is basically from the flask upload tutorial - but here is what is working now.

py file

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from flask.templating import render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1000 * 1000
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/uploads/<name>')
def download_file(name):
    return send_from_directory(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], name)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'curfile' not in request.files or 'newfile' not in request.files:
            flash("Sorry, the upload didn't send all of the data!")
            return redirect(request.url)
        curfile = request.files["curfile"]
        newfile = request.files["newfile"]
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if curfile.filename == "" or newfile.filename == "":
            flash('You need to upload 2 files!')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if curfile and allowed_file(curfile.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(curfile.filename)
            curfile.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
    return render_template("app2.html")
```

template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Upload Current File</h2>
        <input type="file" name="curfile">
        <h2>Upload New File</h2>
        <input type="file" name="newfile">
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class="flashes">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="message_flash">{{ message }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</body>
</html>
```